Counter automaton that recognises $\{ x\ a\ x^T | x \in \{0, 1\}^*, a \not\in \{0, 1\}\}$
I've been recently reading literature on counter machines, and stumbled across Counter Machines and Counter Languages by Fischer, Meyer, and Rosenberg [1].
In Theorem 1.3, they give an informal argument to prove that any real-time deterministic counter machine can't recognise the language $\{ x\ a\ x^T | x \in \{0, 1\}^*, a \not\in \{0, 1\}\}$ (where $x^T$ is the string $x$ reversed) in time less than $2^{\frac{n}{2k}}$. The argument is rather straightforward: a counter machine can recognise such language iff after reading two distinct strings $x, y$ the sum of its counter values is distinct as well. I have a couple of questions about this.
First of all, while in the statement they don't assume anything about the number of counters, is it the case that a counter machine with a single counter can't recognise such language?
Secondly, I'm struggling in coming up with a counter machine that actually recognises the language. I've been trying to tackle the issue as follows: while reading the first part of the input string, add powers of $2$ (if the machine is on $i$-th bit, starting from $i=0$, add add $2^i$ iff the bit is $1$ and $0$ otherwise); then, while reading the second part, subtract the corresponding powers of $2$ (if the first string has a length of $n$ and the machine is on the $i$-th bit of the second string, subtract $2^{(n-i)}$ iff the bit is $1$ and $0$ otherwise). As I want to handle also distinct strings representing the same integer (e.g., $010$ and $10$), I thought of using a second counter to store the length of the first half of the string, then I can easily decrement this counter when reading the second half of the string so that it's 0 iff both "halves" have the same length (and if it reaches $0$ before finishing the second half, transition to a rejecting sink state). The issue I have with this is that I can't think of a way of adding (and subtracting) powers of $2$ to the first counter while reading the input string. Is there any reference online that shows how to do this? Or am I completely off mark with the approach?
Reference
[1] Fischer, Patrick C., Albert R. Meyer, and Arnold L. Rosenberg. "Counter machines and counter languages." Mathematical Systems Theory 2.3 (1968): 265-283.

You can double a counter by adding its value with itself:
$2^{i+1} = 2^i + 2^i$.
You can define addition by repeatedly decrementing one operand while incrementing the other operand.
That definition of addition requires the input and output counters to be all distinct, and destroys their value, so you need a way to move and duplicate values between counters, which are also simple operations to define.

For the sake of spelling things out, those operations are given below in pseudo-code. First we define "add", "duplicate", and "move" in terms of basic instruction that can be relatively easily encoded as transitions in a counter machine (while C != 0 for some counter C, C <- C - 1 (decrement), C <- C + 1 (increment)).
# Add the value of counter C1 to counter C2
# (the counters must be distinct)
# Initial state: C1 = x, C2 = y
# Loop invariant: C1 + C2 = x + y
while C1 != 0:
  C1 <- C1 - 1
  C2 <- C2 + 1
# Final state: C1 = 0, C2 = x + y

# Duplicate the value of counter C0 into C1 and C2
# (the counters must be distinct)
# Initial state: C0 = x, C1 = C2 = 0
# Loop invariant: C0 + C1 = C0 + C2 = x
while C0 != 0:
  C0 <- C0 - 1
  C1 <- C1 + 1
  C2 <- C2 + 1
# Final state: C0 = 0, C1 = C2 = x

# Move the contents of counter C1 into C2
# (the counters must be distinct)
# Initial state: C1 = x, C2 = 0
# Loop invariant C1 + C2 = x
while C1 != 0:
  C1 <- C1 - 1
  C2 <- C2 + 1
# Final state: C1 = 0, C2 = x

We can now denote "add" as the instruction C2 <- C2 + C1, "duplicate" as the instruction C1,C2 <- C0, and move as the instruction C2 <- C1. Be mindful that unlike machine instructions commonly found in modern processors, those instructions always destroy the contents of the input counter(s).
# Double the value of counter C, using two extra counters TMP1 and TMP2 to hold intermediate results
# Using the procedures defined above (add, duplicate, move)
# Initial state: C = x, TMP1 = TMP2 = 0
# Final state: C = 2x, TMP1 = TMP2 = 0
TMP1,TMP2 <- C   # duplicate
C <- TMP1        # move
C <- C + TMP2    # add

We could also have defined doubling on a counter more directly by decrementing it while incrementing twice the output counter at every step, but addition and copying are generally useful to have in counter machines (and other models of computations) so we might as well define and use them. Here it's also an opportunity to show how we can define our own instructions to define higher-level operations in a semi-formal manner.

Ahh, I see! Thanks a lot :) I suppose that the issue I had was that I was trying to do this with just 2 counters (which I thought was feasible to do, but I suppose not at this point). @Hendrik Jan: thanks a lot also for you answer. Indeed, I didn't think of adding the imaginary 1 at the end, it's definitely more elegant than the solution I thought of (having a counter which was used exclusively to compare the length of the two strings)

As for your second question, I assume you want to construct a one-way counter automaton for the language $L$. The paper constructs an efficient two-way automaton.
In your suggestion you represent the $i$-th bit by $2^i$, starting with bit $i=0$.
I think it is more straightforward to transform the binary string $x=x_n \dots x_0$ into its value $\sum_{i=0}^n 2^{x_i}$, that is with most significant bit first. To do this you can use the method explained in the answer by Li_yao Xia. For each letter double the current value on the counter (using a second counter) and add $x_i$. For the second half we reverse the process, dividing the counter by two and compare the remainder with the current symbol.
Indeed, you might need to deal with leading zero's. This can be done by adding an imaginary $1$ at both ends of the string, or by using a ternary representation   $\sum_{i=0}^n 3^{x_i+1}$.
